# Failed to build setup.py on Arch Linux

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, python

I currently installed Arch Linux and I want to install the wxPython module for Spyder3. I had problems installing it with pip. Therefore, I downloaded the wxpython tarball. Here are the steps which I followed:

`cd Downloads
 sudo tar -xvzf wxPython-4.0.6.tar.gz
 cd wxpython-4.0.6`

After that, I wanted to build the setup.py file, but I got this error:

`python setup.py build
 running build
WARNING: Building this way assumes that all generated files have been 
generated already.  If that is not the case then use build.py directly 
to generate the source and perform the build stage.  You can use 
--skip-build with the bdist_* or install commands to avoid this 
message and the wxWidgets and Phoenix build steps in the future.`

`"/usr/bin/python" -u build.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 30, in <module>
    import pathlib2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib2'
Command '"/usr/bin/python" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.`

I also tried `python setup.py install`, but I got here the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix it? All help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ensure pip, setuptools, and wheel are up to date**

While pip alone is sufficient to install from pre-built binary archives, up to date copies of the setuptools and wheel projects are useful to ensure you can also install from source archives:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

**"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathlib2' "**

It means the required module is missing so, try to install the module and try it.

try this

`sudo pip install pathlib2`

or

`sudo pip3 install pathlib2`

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me.